# Where can I get nagoa+.inc

Tags: assembly, nasm

This might sound lame but I have been searching the net since yesterday for this...
Where can I get "nagoa+.inc" which is used for nasm in assembly language. Please not http://forum.nasm.us/ which is not letting my computer in. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://mathimaaran.angelfire.com/nagoa.zip) What you need?

I found this from http://mathimaaran.angelfire.com/links.htm